# Can I change style attribute of an image object on canvas?

Tags: jquery, image, canvas, styles

I have added 2 images on a canvas `drawimage()`, and I want to mix these 2 images for save by using `setAttribute ('class','multiply')` to blend image but it's not working.

Mix-blend-mode: multiply;

Added 2 images:
[image: Added 2 images]

I want to blend multiply:
[image: I want to blend multiply]

Comment: Hello. If you want help, please show more of your code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mix-blend-mode` is CSS attribute. CSS only affects DOM nodes like HTML and SVG elements, not canvas drawing operations. `drawImage` places the pixels of the image on the canvas, but keeps no reference to the actual image or its attributes like class. To multiply pixels on canvas, you can use [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation).

```
ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
ctx.drawImage(image2, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I've try this:
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"
But it's not working with me.

I have to create 2 canvas (as 2 layers) and set style for foreward canvas is "multiply" by:
#canvas{mix-blend-mode: multiply;z-index: 1;}
It can blend now.

 But I can't save the image after blended as one file.

Comment: ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"; //work - make image lighter. But 
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"; //doesn't work

Comment: ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"; //Seems work with shapes only, image object is not

Comment: I have solved this problem with ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply" before draw the second image.

Tks so much!